# Looping through files in different directory given command line argument

Tags: linux, shell

I'm trying to extend a script that implements something like a recycling bin for files on Linux. I have the code that I'm extending at the bottom.

In my extension, when the script is presented with the command line argument `-cleanup` I want to loop through files that are in the `/home/7/bearm/.garbage` directory, and have the user decide whether they want to delete the file or not.

However, I don't know how to detect when the command line argument is there. The command line can have other parameters, I just want to loop through the files when `-cleanup` is used.

I also do not know how to loop through files that are in a different directory (`/home/7/bearm/.garbage`).

How would I go around doing these things?

```
set directory = '/home/7/bearm/.garbage/'

if(! -d "$directory") then
    mkdir .garbage
    mv .garbage /home/7/bearm/
endif

set n = 1

while ($n <= $#argv)
    set file = $argv[$n]
    if(-d $file) then
        #do nothing
        echo "Cannot trash directory $file"
    else
        mv $file /home/7/bearm/.garbage
        echo "Trashed $file"
    endif
    @ n++
end
du -h /home/7/bearm/.garbage
```

Answer (score 1):

To test if arguments contains `-cleanup`, you can do that (tested with `ash` on `Minix3`):

```
if echo "$@" | grep -- "-cleanup" >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    echo "-cleanup is present..."
fi
```

Moreover, if you want a proper solution to use long GNU style options, see http://www.sputnick-area.net/scripts/getopts_long_example.sh and http://www.sputnick-area.net/scripts/getopts_long.sh

---

A `bash` version of your pseudo script :

```
#!/bin/bash

directory='/home/7/bearm/.garbage/'

mkdir -p "$directory"

for arg; do
    if [[ -d $arg ]]; then 
        #do nothing
        echo "Cannot trash directory $arg" >&2
    else    
        mv "$arg" "$directory"
        echo "Trashed $arg"
    fi      
done    

du -sh "$directory"
```

Feel free to improve it with `-cleanup` switch.

Comment: Added bash version of your pseudo script

Comment: Thanks, but how would I loop through the files in .garbage?